# Embedding vs restriction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, category-theory, terminology, relations

*Embedding* is the morphism $( A ; B ; \operatorname{id}_A)$ of the category $\mathbf{Rel}$ for sets $A \subseteq B$.

I call *restriction* the morphism $( A ; B ; \operatorname{id}_B)$ for sets $A \supseteq
B$.

For embedding there is a standard notation: $A \hookrightarrow B$.

Is there a standard notation (and/or terminology) for restriction?

Moreover, is there a notation for $( A ; B ; \operatorname{id}_{A \cap B})$ which
generalizes both embedding and restriction?

Comment: Do you mean something like $f|_{B}$? It hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: @DanielRust: I mean $(A;B)\mapsto(A;B;\operatorname{id}_B)$.

Comment: What if I will name it _common_ of $A$ and $B$? Or maybe _commonization_ of $A$ and $B$. Is the term "common" taken?

Comment: So by $(A;B;\operatorname{id}_B)$ you denote the relation $\{(i(b),b)|b\in B\}$ where $i\colon B\hookrightarrow A$ is the inclusion?

Comment: @roman: yes, I do